# Via Bootstrap, how can I add a vertical divider in a well?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to drawing a well. In this well, I create two `span6` and would like to draw a vertical divider between these two column. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Draw the left border on all, but first column:

```
.well [class^="span"] + [class^="span"] {
    margin-left: -1px; /* compensate border width */
    border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

---

Alternatively, CSS columns can be used (prefixes required):

```
.well.col {
    columns: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-rule: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

If you have never use it before, you should check my [tutorial on CSS columns](http://pavlomykhalov.com/blog/css-multi-column-layout/).

Comment: i believe it breaks it because adding a border adds a small amount of width, if you previously had elements taking up the entire width of the page, than even 1px will push it too far and bounce something down

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer breaks if your elements take up the entire width because the border adds 1px too many!  To combat this you can adjust the margin to account for the border.

```
.line-right {
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you'd like a bigger border, just be sure to account for it in the margin!

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I'd test it too, for some reason when changing the margin-left it wasn't always working.  It could relate to the padding or margin bootstraps classes automatically add

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an HTML `<hr>` tag.

Comment: Seems <hr> is for horizontal line, how can I draw a vertical line?

Comment: As long as you're only implementing a single row layout- it's possible to make the size of the <hr> large but the width very small, the result is a vertical line: <hr width="1" size="500">

Comment: might be possible, but surely invalid.